# MySql - One to Many Join, mapping JOIN with JDBI to List

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I'm trying to write an object query with JDBI that will grab one complete row from the left table and join all matching rows in the right table as a List (one author can have many books).

Author
`id, name, createdAt, updatedAt, email, phoneNumber`

Book
`id, title, authorId, categories, createdAt, updatedAt`

The eventual object I want to create is structured as follows:

```
class AuthorWithBooks() {
  int id,
  String name,
  List<String> categories,
  long createdAt,
  long updatedAt,
  String email,
  String phoneNumber
  List<Book> books
}
```

where book is:

```
class Book {
  id,
  title,
  authorId,
  categories,
  createdAt,
  updatedAt
}
```

Here is the query I'm trying (doesn't grab the Books as List as is)

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT " + AUTHOR_COLUMN MAMES + ", " + BOOK_COLUMN_NAMES + " FROM authors as author" +
      " LEFT JOIN books AS book" +
      " ON author.id = book.authorId" +
      " WHERE id = :authorId")
  List<AuthorWithBooks> getAuthorWithBooks(@Bind("authorId") int authorId);
```

Would appreciate any help/someone pointing me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you need [@UseRowReducer](http://jdbi.org/#__userowreducer)

The implementation for your example would look something like this:

```java
@SqlQuery("SELECT a." + AUTHOR_COLUMN MAMES + ", b." + BOOK_COLUMN_NAMES + " FROM authors as author" +
  " LEFT JOIN books AS book" +
  " ON author.id = book.authorId" +
  " WHERE id = :authorId")
@RegisterBeanMapper(value = Book.class, prefix = "b") 
@RegisterBeanMapper(value = AuthorWithBooks.class, prefix = "a")
@UseRowReducer(AuthorBookReducer.class) 
List<AuthorWithBooks> getAuthorWithBooks(@Bind("authorId") int authorId);

class AuthorBookReducer implements LinkedHashMapRowReducer<Integer, Author> { 
    @Override
    public void accumulate(Map<Integer, Author> map, RowView rowView) {
        Author author = map.computeIfAbsent(rowView.getColumn("a_id", Integer.class), 
                                       id -> rowView.getRow(Author.class));

        if (rowView.getColumn("b_id", Integer.class) != null) { 
            author.getBooks().add(rowView.getRow(Book.class));
        }
    }
}
```